# Segmentation fault caused by `getline`

Tags: c++, linux, getline

Here is the code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main(void)
{
    FILE* file = popen("bash -c \"for i in 1 2 3 4 5;do echo -e -n 'thanks a lot\n'; sleep 1; done\" ", "r");
 
    char* line;
    size_t len;
    if(nullptr != file)
    {
//      std::cout << setvbuf(file, NULL, _IOLBF, 0) << std::endl;
        while(getline(&line, &len, file)>0)
        {
            std::cout << len << std::endl;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I compile the code snippet above with `g++-4.9.4` on `Ubuntu16.04`(i.e. `g++-4.9 popen.cpp -std=c++11 -g`).

It's a surprise that there is a segmentation fault when running the said program.Here is the backstrace:

```
#1  0x00007ffff7735fc8 in _IO_getdelim (lineptr=0x7fffffffe648, n=0x7fffffffe650, delimiter=10, fp=0x613c20) at iogetdelim.c:115
#2  0x00000000004008ff in main () at popen.cpp:16
```

Similar information could be seen at the ouput of [the online compiler](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8001e6487354393):

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Og -Wall -pedantic -fsanitize=undefined,address -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==2528==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x00000000ffef (pc 0x7f2f3748c6ff bp 0x00000000000e sp 0x7ffd7d195e80 T0)
==2528==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
    #0 0x7f2f3748c6ff  (/usr/local/lib64/libasan.so.6+0x276ff)
    #1 0x7f2f375112e4 in realloc (/usr/local/lib64/libasan.so.6+0xac2e4)
    #2 0x7f2f35a43a2a in __getdelim (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x6ea2a)
    #3 0x7f2f374d20e8  (/usr/local/lib64/libasan.so.6+0x6d0e8)
    #4 0x401747 in main (/tmp/1653884701.5067663/a.out+0x401747)
    #5 0x7f2f359f582f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
    #6 0x4010d8 in _start (/tmp/1653884701.5067663/a.out+0x4010d8)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV (/usr/local/lib64/libasan.so.6+0x276ff) 
==2528==ABORTING
```

Could anybody shed some light on this matter?

***Thanks to both Retired Ninja and rici.*** I find where am I wrong now.  Since `char**` is passed to `getline`, I wrongly thought that `getline` will modify the pointer where pointed to and assignment is meaningless.

**UPDATED**:I think I found the answer,but one more question arises.Why the compiler complains that [there is a memory leak](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c761180c4a3d9927)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main(void)
{
    FILE* file = popen("bash -c \"for i in 1 2 3 4 5;do echo -e -n 'thanks a lot\n'; sleep 1; done\" ", "r");
 
    char* line=NULL;
    size_t len;
    if(nullptr != file)
    {
//      std::cout << setvbuf(file, NULL, _IOLBF, 0) << std::endl;
        while(getline(&line, &len, file)>0)
        {
            std::cout << "line=" <<static_cast<void*>(line) <<" len=" << len << ":" << line << std::endl;
            free(line);
            line = NULL;
        }
    }

#ifdef ADD_EXTRA_FREE
    std::cout << "line=" << static_cast<void*>(line)  <<" len=" << len << std::endl;  //extra free is needed, otherwise the compiler complain there is a memory leak.
    free(line);
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Og -Wall -pedantic -fsanitize=undefined,address -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
line=0x60c000000040 len=120:thanks a lot

line=0x60c000000100 len=120:thanks a lot

line=0x60c0000001c0 len=120:thanks a lot

line=0x60c000000280 len=120:thanks a lot

line=0x60c000000340 len=120:thanks a lot


=================================================================
==7574==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 120 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7ff877ae8f9f in malloc (/usr/local/lib64/libasan.so.6+0xabf9f)
    #1 0x7ff87601b9e7 in __getdelim (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x6e9e7)
    #2 0x401f6a in main (/tmp/1653885921.5976012/a.out+0x401f6a)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 120 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

**I think the compiler is wrong** since I always free the memory allocated by `getline` when `getline` is successfully invoked.

**Updated**:
Thanks to @kaylum, I notice what the manual has clearly said that:

> This buffer should be freed by the user program even if getline() failed.

Comment: `line` is uninitialized. If you want `getline` to allocate the memory for you then you need to pass a pointer to a NULL pointer.

Comment: `line` is uninitialised. It must be either NULL or a pointer to a block of dynamically allocated storage. [man getline](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)

Comment: You are using C++ headers and C++ I/O — this isn't C code.

Comment: @rici Thank you for the clarification. I fully understand where am I wrong now. But I try to make the code snippet correct, I face a [memory leak](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c761180c4a3d9927). I think the compiler is wrong. Could you please shed some light on this matter?

Comment: Blaming the compiler is rarely correct. What happens if you define `ADD_EXTRA_FREE`? The [manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) clearly says it needs to be freed even if `getline` fails: "*This buffer should be
       freed by the user program even if getline() failed.*"

Comment: @kaylum Sorry for my poor English. I didn't notice that. Thank you for your generous help. It's really out of my expectation that the buffer should be freed **even if getline() failed**. Kinda like I have to call `free` even if `malloc` fails.

Comment: You should expect to free the buffer even if the first call to `getline()` reports EOF.  It allocates memory, then checks to see if there is data to read.